# LINQ to Entity Relationship

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Hello I am a Entity Framework newb and I am trying to get the following code into a single query for a data relationship. The relationship is one to many.

The code that does not work:

```
var categories = db.DataModel.Categories
    .Where(c => c.CategoryTypeID == getCategoryTypeID(selectedId));

int getCategoryTypeID(int selectedTypeId)
{
    return db.DataModel.CategoryLinkTypes.Where(l => l.ID == selectedTypeId)
        .FirstOrDefault().ToInt(0);
}
```

I hope you can see what I am trying to do. When I run this code I get this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 getCategoryTypeID(Int32)' 
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Can someone show me the proper way to do this?

I am using EF 4 + and C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try pulling your function out of the link query:

```
int categoryTypeId = getCategoryTypeID(selectedId);

var categories = db.DataModel.Categories
    .Where(c => c.CategoryTypeID == categoryTypeId);
```

Comment: Glad this worked for you. Just out of curiosity, which did you go with?

Comment: I used the 2nd option only because it turned out I had more then one object to deal with in my relation. So it was just one table to another. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Makes sense -- the first option was actually flawed. It would have returned an IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Category>>. I'm just going to remove it for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot still invoke a function like that in the query. But you should be able to extract the logic in the function, make it an expression and use that inside the query. Hope, it's clear.

Comment: Hello, like this? var categories = db.DataModel.Categories.Where(c => c.CategoryTypeID == db.DataModel.CategoryLinkTypes.Where(l => l.ID == selectedTypeId).FirstOrDefault().ToInt(0));

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what this error is saying is that it cannot translate the getCategoryTypeID into a SQL statement(or whatever persistance layer you are using). In your code this makes sense, but keep in mind that this code is turned into a query, and if the compiler does not know how to make that query off of your function, then it will not be able to pull anything back.

An option would be to `JOIN` the two tables and run your where directly against the `CategoryLinkTypes`.

Another option would be to change your function to return a `Queryable`, but I think the `JOIN` might be simpler in this case

Example of JOIN (I believe this should work :)):

```
db.DataModel.Categories
    .Join(
        db.DataModel.CategoryLinkTypes, //What you are joining
        category=>category.CategoryTypeID, //Right Side
        categoryLinkType=>categoryLinkType.CategoryTypeID, //Left Side
        (category, categoryLinkType) =>  //Creation of new, combined object
            new{LinkTypeId = categoryLinkType.Id, 
                Category = category}
    )
    .Where(x=>x.LinkTypeId == selectedId)
    .Select(x=>x.Category); //We only want the Category
```

Comment: Can you show me an example of a JOIN? Does that use the .Include("X")?

Comment: Include is more for overriding lazy loading. Join is what will be used to create your query in the back end. I have updated my example

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have setup your database properly with foreign keys, and then generated navigation properties.  You should be able to do something like this (since i can't see your actual data model, i'm just guessing, but you should get the idea)

```
var categories = db.DataModel.Categories
    .Where(c => c.CategoryType.CategoryLinkTypeID == SelectedTypeID);
```

If you were to edit your question and include the definitions of Categories and CategoryType entities it might help.